# Array of arrays in foreach-object

Tags: powershell

```
> (1..3 | % { $_ * 2 })[0]
2

> (1..3 | % { $_, $_ * 2 })[0]
1

> (1..3 | % { @($_, $_ * 2) })[0]
1
```

The first example makes sense, I loop an array of 3 elements and get back 3 elements. But I would expect the two others to return the array [1,2] (that is, an array of 3 elements each one an array of two elements where the first is the array [1,2].

Why didn't they and how can I fix that?

Comment: Real programmers can write Perl in any language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but doesn't feel like this is the right approach.

However, you can construct the statement in the following way to create an array of arrays and select the first element:

```
> (1..3 | % { ,($($_), $($_*2)) })[0]
1
2
```

Comment: yes, just figured it out and you beat me to deleting the question ;-). The question is what is the meaning of the magical comma?

Comment: It adds a dimension. When appending to an array, powershell flattens it first by default, using the comma ensures the element type is preserved